# How to upgrade pulseaudio

Tags: 12.10, sound, upgrade, pulseaudio

I got some issues with sound, sometimes it freezes and get out of sync with picture. VLC is giving me error, and there is said that I should update to pulseaudio 3.0. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and pulseaudio is

```
$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 2.1
```

Shall I upgrade? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With upgrade to 13.04 pulseaudio updated to version 3.0 and problems disappeared.

Answer (score 9):

You can install pulseaudio 2.0 from the `ubuntu-audio-dev` ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```